# Add directory in the middle of a URL with hataccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

My current .htacces file looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I am trying to accomplish (as well as the above) is to change a url such as `http://domain.com/pages/pagename` to something like `http://domain.com/index.php/pages/view/pagename`.

Keeping in mind that I still require urls without the /page/ part such as `http://domain.com/search` to go to `http://domain.com/index.php/search`. I am working with CodeIgniter.

What I have come up with so far is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/pages/index/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# /pages/ specific rule
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ index.php/pages/index/$1 [L]
# everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The above assumes that `http://domain.com/pages/` is not a real folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /index.php/pages/index/$1
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified my .htaccess file to be

`DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/(.*) ./index.php/page/index/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

But now the page 404's. Any ideas?